# Highcharts - Annotations outside plot area (top/bottom)- doesn't show up

Tags: highcharts, annotations

I have an issue with setting annotations above plot area. When I inspect chart in the console I see that annotation is rendered it's just label doesn't show up.

I browsed highcharts forum and found this topic: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=39918 where @ppotaczek created livedemo http://jsfiddle.net/ppotaczek/j4m2vzaa/ to answer someone's question, and i think I have a similar situation. Am I missing something?
 Can someone suggest me a workaround? Thanks!

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
      'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
    ]
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Annotations'
  },

  series: [{
    data: [{
      y: 29.9,
      id: 'min'
    }, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, {
      y: 216.4,
      id: 'max'
    }, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }],

  annotations: [{
    labelOptions: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
      verticalAlign: 'top'
    },
    labels: [{
        y: 55,
      point: {
        xAxis: 0,
        yAxis: 0,
        x: 1,
        y: 0
      },
      text: 'label1'
    }, {
        y: 55,
      point: {
        xAxis: 0,
        yAxis: 0,
        x: 3,
        y: 0
      },
      text: 'label2',
      backgroundColor: 'white'
    }]
  }]
});
```

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyFF0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for sharing this issue, it is a regression. I just reported this bug on Highcharts GitHub issue channel.

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12897

If you need temporary workaround please ask about it in the comment under the above link. The core developers should respond to you quickly.